# How to check all user(s) to see if they're online in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

My goal is to check all user(s) in my **users table** to see if they're online using `Laravel 4`.
I'm also interested in who's not logged-in as well.
Later on, I want to print out 2 separate lists of who's online and who's not ?

- Is there **quick** way out to display that ?
- Do I have use `Auth::check()` that came with Laravel ?
- Do I need to update anything on my `database` ?

**Sample**

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to know if the user is still on your website. You can only use some ways to guess if they are.

The most commonly used way is by saving the timestamp on which a user last visited a page. If you say that a user stays on one page for one minute you can say that the user is online if there is less then one minute time between the last timestamp and the current timestamp.

Facebook uses a sort of ping function to check this. They send an ajax request to the server every x seconds. That way they know the user is still on the website.

Comment: I like your answer more. Can you please help me a little bit more ? Can you me a quick starter code in Laravel if possible. I totally agree with your idea.

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest some logics to you.

- Yes, you need to update your database. Your **users** table.
  I suggest at a column called : is_online , tinyInt , 0 or 1.

After you have that,

- In your **Sign-In** function, somewhere at the end before you redirect.

  `set is_online = '1';` // this should be save into your database now.
- Apply the same similar logic in your **Sign-Out** function,somewhere at the end before you redirect.

  ```
  set is_online = '0';
  ```

Don't forget to save  !! by doing `$user->save();` any time you update any info on your database.

**Print your list**
You can do

```
For all the user()->is_online = '1' OR user()->is_online = '0'
// Do any programming logic with it, print it or whatever ...
```

Give it a try ! if you stuck, post some code, I will help you through it.

Comment: How about if a user does not log out? He/She will be online forever.

Comment: Good call. @Iggy : Have you ever thing of that ?

Comment: You can do a session timeout and set the variables accordingly..! :D

Comment: @iggy: Don't get me wrong, your logic get me at least thinking about the flow of this. Thanks for getting me thinking ...

Comment: @ChintanParekh : would you please help by suggest some starter code ? I will try my test to take care of the rest.

Comment: I kind of agree with @Jerodev answer. There is no real way to identify except pinging the server..I will try to put a small solution maybe by tomorrow..

Comment: @ChintanParekh : Well that being said, where should I set the is_online = 0 ? app/config/session.php ?

Comment: Well, basically the idea was, setting up the value as suggested by @igy and then based on the timeout (you can have a javascript/ajax pinging script to the server every "X minutes" and then based on the last activity performed you can calculate the timeout )..for that you need to always update "last_activity_performed" (some field in database) when any database activity  is performed..I hope I am clear..(It is not an optimal solution, but I believe it is kind of the only way, as mentioned by @jerodev). Happy Coding :! :)

Comment: I understand most of your comments. Thanks for your help. You mentioned, **Base on the time out**. May I asked how do I get that ? Where should I do it in Laravel ? I got the database part and all the logics that iggy suggested. I was hoping for a little more hints from you.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same question and solved it the following way (Laravel 5):

1. Create a migration that adds the field 'last_online' to your users table

> ```
> class AddLastOnlineToUsersTable extends Migration
> {
>     public function up()
>     {
>         Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
>         {
>             $table->dateTime('last_online');
>         });
>     }
>
>
>     public function down()
>     {
>         Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
>         $table->dropColumn('last_online');
>     });
> }
> ```

Don't forget to add the new field to the $fillable and $dates arrays in the User model.

2. if you use an abstract Controller class as basis for all of your controllers (if not, you should consider it), you can add the following to this Controller:

> ```
> abstract class Controller extends BaseController 
> {
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->user = Auth::user();
>         if($this->user)
>         {
>             $this->user->last_online = Carbon::now();
>             $this->user->save();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Create a GetUsersOnlineRepository (or, alternatively a service) with the following function (don't forget to include Carbon\Carbon and the User model):

> ```
> public function getAllUsersOnline($seconds_since_last_activity = 300)
> {
>     $last_activity = Carbon::now()->subSeconds($seconds_since_last_activity);
>     $online_users = User::where('last_online', '>=', $last_activity)->get(['id', 'user_name']);
>     return $online_users;
> }
> ```

4. In your controller, call the function getAllUsersOnline() in this new repository/service.